# Adding a Contact to a Campaign via the Campaign History Related List in Lightning

Tags: lightning, related-list, campaign

In Lightning...

- when I am on a contact page looking at the Campaign History related list, I select Add to Campaign.
- I select the Campaign I want (happens on all of them)
- Click Next
- The screen flickers and takes me back to the Contact record.  The Campaign relationship is not established.
- This does not happen in Classic.  This happens in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the list view for Campaigns set correctly.  Once I set the correct fields in the view, I was able to add Contacts to Campaigns.